# How to insert a date in format "dd/mm/yyyy" in SQL?

Tags: sql, date, insert

I have the following table:

```
drop table if exists Activity;
create table Activity (

    id_activity serial,
    type varchar(255),
    day date
    primary key (id_activity)
);
```

I have to insert different values to this table. The issue is that the date format accepts this format by default "yyyy/mm/dd" and I have to insert the date in format "dd/mm/yyyy".

This is what I'm trying:

```
insert into Activity (type, day) values ("football", [What should I type here?]);
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Why do you "have to" insert the date in that format?

Comment: I'm using MySql and I have to insert the date in that format because I am required so

Answer (score 0):

try this

> insert into Activity (type, day) values ("football", CONVERT(date,
>   YourDateValue, 103))

[You can get the reference here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp)

Comment: is that specific to sql server?

Comment: This is not working, the format is not useful in this example